# How to run JDBC update query without knowing column type

Tags: jdbc

I have to run a jdbc update query using preparedstatement/statement without knowing the column type. 
I have a query say ' update table set status=? where id=? '
and i am getting a map of values like {("status"="123"), ("id"="546")}

Now I don't know the column type, is there any generic way to run this query using jdbc?

Instead of running -  ps.setString(1,map.get(("status"));
beacause i don't know the column type of status field in DB (it may be a int also)

Please help me in solving this without using spring jdbc templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ps.setString(1,map.get(("status"))` will work for integer also, you just has to take care that `value` you are putting in integer column is of `int` type.

Following code explains that:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class SOJDBC 
{
public static void main(String rgs[])
{
    Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection("TEMP");
    try 
    {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into STUDENT(ROLLNO,NAME,AGE) values(?,?,?)");
        pstmt.setString(1, "1");    //column type is integer, will work because the value is of int type
        pstmt.setString(2, "Bhushan");
        pstmt.setString(3, "25");   //column type is integer, will work because the value is of int type
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```